# Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.infoWindow is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-maps

While trying to implement a google maps marker I've got this error and just couldn't get rid of it.

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.infoWindow is not a constructor
>
> > at addMarker (functions.js:25)
> > at window.onload (functions.js:36)

My code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var map;

    function initialize(){
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.648598,-48.577423),
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        }   

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"),mapProp);
    }

    function addMarker(lat,long,icon,content){
        var latLng = {'lat':lat,'lng':long};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:latLng, 
            map:map,
            icon:icon
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.infoWindow({
            content:content,
            maxWidth:200,
            pixelOffSet: new google.maps.Size(0,20)
        });

        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    }


    initialize();
    addMarker(-27.616637,-48.5923228,'','address');
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the very basic [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview) in the docs. No `window.onload()` - instead they load the api with a callback parameter which is set to `inititalize` which will call the `initialize` function when the maps api script has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. JavaScript is case sensitive, `InfoWindow` in the constructor should be capitalized; `google.maps.infoWindow` is not the same as `google.maps.InfoWindow`

[image]

**Working Code snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var map;

    function initialize(){
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.648598,-48.577423),
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        }   

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"),mapProp);
    }

    function addMarker(lat,long,icon,content){
        var latLng = {'lat':lat,'lng':long};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:latLng, 
            map:map,
            icon:icon
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:content,
            maxWidth:200,
            pixelOffSet: new google.maps.Size(0,20)
        });

        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    }


    initialize();
    addMarker(-27.616637,-48.5923228,'','address');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#mapa {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="mapa"></div>
```

Comment: Why the use of `onload` and the `initAutocomplete` callback param (and places lib)?

Comment: Just a typo/copy paste error.  Thanks for identifying that, now fixed.